# Disable Zoom effect in avplayer when do double tap ios

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, avplayer

Hi in my application i am using AvplayerViewcontroller and adding tap gestures on AvplayerViewcontroller.view when double tap i want to show program details. I can able to show but along with that Video is zooming. I don't want that zoom effect. To disable this even i tried by disabling userInteraction for avplayer but that time even gestures are also not taking user actions (taps).Even i added another uiview on player view and added gestures on top that but still no use. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you adding the view as subview to your playerView?

Comment: Yes i tried that also.

Comment: Can you post your code here in the question itself.

Comment: Yes no problem but i have share total class only. Because i am creating subclass for avplayerviewcontroller and same i am using.

Comment: I added main method which i am using.

Comment: Can you please check and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** @NareshGadamsetty Checkout this.

if `showsPlaybackControls=false` then you can simply add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `contentOverlayView`

```
class MyPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func addPlayer()
        ...
        ...

        showsPlaybackControls=false

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showDetail))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        contentOverlayView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func showDetail() {
        // Do whatever you want to do in this method
    }
}
```

Otherwise implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
class MyPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func addPlayer()
        ...
        ...
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.tapCount == 2 {
            showDetail()
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    private func showDetail() {
        // Do whatever you want to do in this method
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried but that time even what ever gestures i added those were also losing userinteraction.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a UIView as subView with clear backgroundColor to player's view and add your required gesture on that view. Like:

[playerViewController.view addSubview:YourView];